How can I increase the width of the Edge DevTools Console filter textbox?
As you can see in the image below, the filter textbox is stupidly narrow, especially considering all of the available horizontal space.  How can I increase the width of that filter textbox and have it persist?

I can temporarily do it by inspecting the primary devtools window and directly modify the style accordingly, but I've not found a way to do it in such a way that it persists.  I've tried Tampermonkey, Stylus, Tampermonkey + Stylus, a custom devtools extension... haven't been able to crack this nut.
The custom extension seems to lack the context/permissions to access the main devtools DOM.
Stylus can't do it since it can't pierce the shadow root/DOM.
I installed a Tampermonkey script that injects Stylus scripts into each shadow root, but I didn't get that working, either.  Maybe I'm not targeting the domain/URL/whatever correctly...

Why is it fixed at such a stupidly narrow width?  I mean, just let it flex and grow to fill the available horizontal space...
How can I tweak it?

*** EDIT 1
I changed the title to reflect the Edge browser specifically.  I noticed that the Chrome browser's filter box does expand to fill the entire toolbar as it should.  It's only Edge that doesn't.  I opened bug report here:  https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/298

No way, Chromium developers have removed the possibility in https://crbug.com/369788368.
